# How to enable C++17 mode with UnrealEngine 4.19 on VS 2017?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

UnrealEngine 4.19 uses Visual Studio 2017's C++14 mode as default. The Visual Studio 2017 compiler has a flag `/std:c++17` to enable C++17 and subsequently things like `<optional>` for `std::optional`.

I tried adding the following line to VCToolChain.cs (`C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.19\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\Platform\Windows\VCToolChain.cs`):

```
void AppendCLArguments_Global(CppCompileEnvironment CompileEnvironment, VCEnvironment EnvVars, List<string> Arguments)
    {
        Arguments.Add("/std:c++17");
        // ... the rest of this function.
```

However this doesn't seem to do anything, for example `#include <optional>` still results in the build error `fatal error C1189: #error:  class template optional is only available with C++17.`.
It's immensely difficult to find out anything about this or even try to find out with that compiler flags the UnrealBuildTool (UBT) is calling `cl.exe`... Other answers suggested to add `-verbose` to the nmake "Build Command Line" setting (so mine looks like: `"C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.19\Engine\Build\BatchFiles\Build.bat" DemoApp Win64 DebugGame "$(SolutionDir)$(ProjectName).uproject" -WaitMutex -FromMsBuild -verbose` but all it does is output verbose UBT messages, not compiler command-line invocation output.

Comment: Would it work to add it to the project file through the Language tab?

Comment: @Carl if you refer to the "normal" VS project settings under "Properties": There is no such thing in Unreal Engine projects. As mentioned, UE has its own build system, so there isn't any Language tab or settings to change there. At all.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer : Add `-CppStd=Cpp17` to your `UnrealBuildTool.exe` compile command.

Strangely, this seems to be documented nowhere, I had to dig into the .cs files of the engine to find it.

More specifically, in the file "C:/Program Files (x86)/Epic Games/UE_4.26/Engine/Source/Programs/UnrealBuildTool/Configuration/TargetRules.cs", there is :

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Which C++ stanard to use for compiling this target
        /// </summary>
        [RequiresUniqueBuildEnvironment]
        [CommandLine("-CppStd")]
        [XmlConfigFile(Category = "BuildConfiguration")]
        public CppStandardVersion CppStandard = CppStandardVersion.Default;
```

Then, in another file, the definition of `CppStandardVersion` is :

```
 public enum CppStandardVersion
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Use the default standard version
        /// </summary>
        Default,

        /// <summary>
        /// Supports C++14
        /// </summary>
        Cpp14,

        /// <summary>
        /// Supports C++17
        /// </summary>
        Cpp17,

        /// <summary>
        /// Latest standard supported by the compiler
        /// </summary>
        Latest,
    }
```

So, I have generated my project files with `-cmakefile`, then I have opened my `CMakeLists.txt` and added `-CppStd=Latest` to my `Build.bat` compile command, and the error with `std::optional` is gone !